# lotus notes: @Command(fileprint) with the print/page setup box

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

```
@Command([FilePrint]; "1"; ""; ""; ""; "printview";""; "";"";"")
```

I'm using this formula in an action button inside a view for printing all documents listed by the view.

I've looked in the Domino Designer but I didn't found any parameter for the page setup which I want to appear.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Command([FilePageSetup]);
```

To display the page setup dialog just before the FilePrint command.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FILEPAGESETUP.html